# sending commands to tk103 gps tracker

Tags: php, gps

I'm working on a realtime gps tracker web application using php.
The tracker reference is tk103, I can receive information from the tracker and store it into database.

GPRS mode of the device is enabled, my question is :

How can I send command from my server to the device using php.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you had any leads on this? I'm also curious.

Answer (score 1):

it' depends on which protocol are you using to send data from tk103 device to server if you are using TCP/IP protocol once data came from device you should replay back with your command.

you show configure in device to ask or invoke to request for command.

we are configure like
1)  `imei:359710047059226,tracker,15/03/18 12:17,,F,121703.000,A,1255.2746,N,07736.8209,E,0.00,208.00,0.00,1,0;`

id device send this command we are storing only to data base

2) `imei:359710047059226,tracker,15/03/18 12:17,,F,121703.000,A,1255.2746,N,07736.8209,E,0.00,208.00,0.00,1,1;`

last bit data we are testing 
 if 0 means only storing replay with :OK
 if 1 means replay with :CMD GPRS 001 like some commands

```
[`#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '192.168.1.53';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

`][1](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php)